# Burn average value in raster to grids

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon

I'm working on Qgis 3.8 , I have a mold filled with squares, I would like to burn the average value within each square of other vector or raster file.
[image: Mold]

This is the vectoriced file with all the data that I want to burn in those squares

[image: Vector]

This is the original raster file [image: Raster]

In the past I have done it (this isn't the final file, it's similar to how it should look), but now I can't remember how, neihter find the post that helped me with that. 
[image]

Lowering the resolution of the raster file won't be usefull, because I am comparing different rasterfiles that have to have the same resolution and squares with data and without data in order to be compared in R Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Zonal Statistics tool to calculate the average raster cells within polygon grid. Just search for Zonal Statistics and you will find it as in the image below.

[image]

Comment: If you have multiple rasters, you can still use this method. Just run Zonal Stats once for each raster, so that it builds up new fields on the same vector layer. Then use the Field Calculator to calculate the average of all the fields. If you add the "count" stat as well as the mean, you can calculate a weighted average.